# Converting AutoCAD drawings to QGIS shapefiles

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, autocad, dwg

I am having problems converting an AutoCAD 2012 drawing (.dwg) file to a shapefile (.shp) in a QGIS project I am working on using the Coordinate Reference System **NAD_1983_StatePlane_Indiana_East_FIPS_1301_Feet**. My main problem is that the shapefiles are not located on the correct coordinates nor is object scale correct. What am I doing wrong here? I know there are questions regarding AutoCAD/QGIS conversions, but I am teaching myself and I need a little more help on the basics.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of your inputs and if any errors are occurring when you try to convert using that CRS you've selected
?

Comment: The insert photo command seems to be broken right now. One question I had relating to this was about the CRS. Say I have my drawing in AutoCAD at specific coordinates; when I import it into QGIS using "Add vector layer", does it insert the drawing at those coordinates relative to the origin of that CRS?